# I wanted to make a scheduled screenshot and then automatically send it to telegram using bot using python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, telegram, scheduler

here is the code

```
import schedule
import pyautogui as pag
import requests as req
import datetime as dt
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import time


baseurl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot6930441389:AAHTiHu_x7j_V85OMuLZpPCADXSrn1FqgYg/sendPhoto"

now = dt.datetime.now()

dnt = now.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
dir = r'D:\mik\py\testhttp\ss.jpeg'

parameter = {
    "chat_id" : "-4080615403",
    "caption" : dnt 
}
my_file = open(r'D:\mik\py\testhttp\ss.jpeg', "rb")

files = {
    "photo" : my_file
}


def ssjob():
    ss = pag.screenshot()
    ss.save(r'D:\mik\py\testhttp\ss.jpeg')
    respond = req.get(baseurl, data = parameter, files=files)

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(ssjob,"cron", day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='14', minute='50')
scheduler.start()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep
```

but every time the script runs, it immediately screenshot the time now (lets say 14:49:34) and send it to telegram using bot at the scheduled time (14:50)

i try to set the scheduled task to actually screenshot the screen at the scheduled time (14:50) and then send it to telegram. not screenshot the current time and then send it to telegram at the scheduled time.